# Google apps script post-install tooltip

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created an add-on in Google Apps Script. There has to be post-install tool tip in add-on. The tool tip is seen at the add-on menu item after installation is complete. Could any one please tell me what is the method to do so or what is the exact procedure to show the tool-tip post install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post install tool-tip seen when installing an Addon is not built into the Addon itself, rather it's provided at the time that you publish the Addon. This isn't well documented however, merely lightly implied under ['Publishing instructions'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) -> 'Prepare and deploy your add-on' when it says 'In the Deploy as Add-on dialog, fill all required fields. The add-on’s name must be the same as the name of the Apps Script project. See the style guide for more information on the other fields.'

The [Style Guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style) then has a section on the ['Post-install tip'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/style#post-install_tip), implying that this is when it's filled. It could, however, be a lot clearer.

Comment: I have already read those instructions. I thought I missed something and one has to implement it. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the script you go to "Publish > Deploy as Docs add-on..." and from there you can add a Post-install tip.